# "Permission Denied" when trying to login in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I recently got VS on a new computer (have been using it for over 1 year) and I used it without logging in for 30 days after which it asked me to log in. When I tried, this happened:

[image: My error]

Tried reinstalling, tweaking IE settings and making it the default browser, deleting cache, deleting some files, making sure it's not blocked by the firewall, but nothing worked.

What can I do? I really need to make it work fast.

Comment: If youre gonna downvote it, at least provide a reason, or help me

Comment: I have the same problem, so you are not alone. I don't know why someone would downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my default IE9 to an IE11, turned all settings all the way down and I was able to log in!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads

Don't know if this will help everyone, but it did for me

Comment: Sounds plausible. I imagine the remote website involved just doesn't work with such an ancient browser any more (0.48% market share!) and is using JavaScript features not supported in IE9. Interestingly, though, IE9 is still technically supported by Microsoft so this is potentially a bit of a f###-up on their part.

Comment: Yeah I'll report it to them and hopefully the other people that possibly had this happen will finally be able to use VS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this as admin?

Comment: Doubt it has anything to do with that

Comment: I have had some weird things happen when using Visual Studio and Windows.  One of the reasons why I switched over to Linux; too many quirky things that kept happening.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't log in, but I went to MSDN account and took the Visual Studio key and entered it. It's still not logged in, but it works.